# Typeorm - cannot connect to postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, orm, typeorm

I created Typeform project, but I can not connect to Postgres.

I followed step by step from the documentation.

1. npm install typeorm -g
2. typeorm init --name MyProject --database postgres
3. cd MyProjectnpm install

then I runed command npm start and this is output

> MyProject@0.0.1 start /Users/marek/Documents/works/test/MyProject
>   ts-node src/index.ts

marek@Mareks-MacBook-Pro MyProject %

The output is without errors but the script can not connect, I know it because the expected output is "console.log("Connected.");"

This is code

```
createConnection().then(async connection => {
  console.log("Connected.");
}).catch(error => console.log("error: " + error));
```

This part "console.log("error: " + error)" returned nothing.

I change the other Postgres server and the output was the same.
I change parameters type in ormconfig.json to MySQL everything was OK.

Has somebody an Idea?

Thank you.